# Reliable browser detection with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a website, and offcourse like most websites it loads faster in Firefox.

I want to create some form of a bar, which displays on top of my site, whenever a user without FF enters the site.
This bar will say something like "Install FF for better performance etc etc..."

How should I do this? Browser detection I guess, but there are tons of different codes out there. Any code you all know that is more reliable, and better to use?

Btw, does anybody know if I need permission from Mozilla to have such a bar on my website?

Thanks

EDIT: FF IS NOT THE FASTEST BROWSER, I GOT IT!

Comment: IQ interlude! Firefox stands to Lynx as a Ferrari to a ......

Comment: ... with an 80x25 text-based radar screen.

Comment: Why are people even giving answers or comments to a completely different topic than the question. The question is how to detect a browser, and I NEVER in the question say anything like "FF is faster than Chrome or Lynx". Please, stick to the question.

Comment: @Carman — discussion about the merits of what you want to do is not a completely different topic to the question, and you said "it loads faster in Firefox" and "a user without FF". While you didn't mention any other specific browser, the implication is that you are talking about all browsers (otherwise, why wouldn't you say, for example, "in Firefox then IE" and "a user with IE"?).

Comment: @David - I disagree, the comment you gave ("Firefox is nowhere near as fast as Lynx") has very very little to do with this question, if anything at all.

Comment: Clearly a (humorous) speed comparison between two browsers is completely irrelevant to a question about how to moan at people because of the speed of their browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(Skipping all the arguments on whether what you want to do is a good or a bad thing. Assuming you really like Firefox and want to promote it.)*

1. Use the `navigator` object to check if the browser is Firefox. `navigator.appCodeName`, `navigator.appName`, `navigator.appVersion`. What you want to do is not a critical part of your website, so you don't need a fail-safe detection method. If it works for over 95% of your targeted users than the method is good.
2. I doubt you need permission to advertise a free product. Mozilla even [encourages](http://www.spreadfirefox.com/affiliates/homepage) you to do so.

Answer (score 8):

You may be interested in this page here on spreadfirefox.com: http://www.spreadfirefox.com/affiliates/utw. It contains a set of Spread Firefox buttons, but what's more interesting is the code that comes with it. You'll notice that the button's image will actually change depending on which browser you view it on:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/utw/3.6/FF36_36_120x240.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/utw/3.6/FF36_FF_120x240.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/utw/3.6/FF36_IE_120x240.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/utw/3.6/FF36_OTHER_120x240.png))</sub>

Looking at the [**Javascript code**](https://web.archive.org/web/20120504094550/http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/utw/switch-36.js), you can see that they're already doing the work for you:

```
/* *********************************************
This code came from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html 
In order for this to function properly, it must be updated regularly
***********************************************/
```

So why not just modify the code they've given to work with your images or code? Or better yet, use one of their ready made ones?

Answer (score 6):

**jQuery** has [browser detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

The jQuery dev's themselves however argue that you shouldn't select on browser, but on what features are supported by the browser. Thus they recommend [browser feature detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) instead. Makes sense.

Comment: this was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 100% reliable browser detection. Accessing the userAgent-string provided by the navigator-object is not reliable while it can be faked by the user. Accessing some properties that only exist in a special browser now, may be reliable right now, but not in the future, because you never know, if another browser will apply this property sometimes or the property will be removed from the browser in future versions.

Comment: If the user fakes the userAgent then it's clear he doesn't have any intention to change browsers. So no detection is needed in this case. Note that this detection is needed only for promoting. Firefox isn't actually needed to view the site.

Answer (score 4):

This might not answer your question, but you can make conditional comments in your HTML code like this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

You can use this code to detect any IE version.

Unless you are hired by the Mozilla Foundation, I don't see why users with Chrome and Safari and similar browsers should be notified with this message. They made an active choice and picked their own browser, something you can't say about most IE users who might be unaware of the alternatives.
Mainly, it's Internet Explorer that is the problem.

Sorry if this was slightly off-topic and if it wasn't helpful at all.

/ end of moral rant ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think browser detection is not the right way to solve some issues. If your code is slow on other browser you should first investigate the reason, clean and optimize your code, then if you don't solve you could optionally provide a reduced functionality for other browser.

But please, avoid suggesting user what he should install in its computer

Comment: ok, no problem for downvote. This is what I really think. Browser detection is last option, at least for me. I don't like hide the dust under the carpet

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I get a -1 because I don't like Firefox or because I didn't give you the solution in your hand for you to copy and paste? Well here you go people:

```
<!--[if IE]>
Special instructions for IE
<![endif]-->
```

And in jQuery

```
if ($.browser.msie)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's such a good idea. What about other browsers such as Chrome or Safari? Right now, Chrome is faster than Firefox (Sunspider tests), so your statement "it loads faster in Firefox" is not really correct. Faster than what? If you mean IE, then there are already solutions around the web for alerting users not to use IE and switch to something else. You shouldn't favorize just one browser.

Comment: Depends on the webpage, mine loads faster with FF. And it is not only speed I am after, FF does the job better than Chrome, Safari I am not so experienced with.

Comment: Your website is not a unique snowflake. Unless it is a technology demonstration of bleeding edge browser features (in which case the audience is smart enough to recognise a title like "Demonstration of Firefox's new -moz-smell property") then I'm not going to switch browsers just because one (which I find to be, in general, rather slow) is supposedly faster at rendering your site then my preferred browser. You time might be better spent trying to improve the performance, perhaps by profiling any JS you have in other browsers to find where the slow parts are and improving them.