# How to get a name of browser by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable browser detection with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213222/reliable-browser-detection-with-javascript)

How to get a name of browser by using JavaScript?

I expected to see only the name like this Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc.

Comment: This is bad practice. Don't do it

Comment: I understand why its duplicated... why don't you read it again that what i asking for? 

forget it!  I found the solution can do that ------ > 

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're *sure* you need it: `jQuery.browser`.  Promise you'll only use it as a last resort.

Comment: -1 don't recommend `jQuery.browser` It will be deprecated in later versions. This should _not_ be used.

Comment: @Raynos -- did you actually read my answer?  Did it sound like I was *recommending* `jQuery.browser` to you?  And, will we're pointing out obvious stuff, it **isn't** deprecated, they just recommend against it *just like I did*!  Grrr.

Comment: straight from the docs "The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3" I don't think it's nice to even mention deprecated features.

Comment: I was assuming you were advising against it because user agent detection is, in general, a bad idea rather then because jQuery had deprecated it.

Comment: The [*live* docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) don't say deprecated.  The reason for **not** using `jQuery.browser` has nothing to do with release schedules, it just tempts you down a path of "if this browser, do this; if that browser, do something else," which is a trap.  Some times, you just want to use the name of the browser for something: logging, testing, saying to the user, "Hey, what kinda idiot uses Internet Explorer?"  `jQuery.browser` is wonderfully useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), but read the warning, it's better to detect features. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to confidently "get" only the name in a cross browser manner.

The best you can do is hack around with regular expressions on `window.navigator.userAgent` and hope future browsers don't break it.

But the `userAgent` is a mess. Don't touch it.

The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#system-state-and-capabilities%3a-the-navigator-object) claims that

> window . navigator . appName
>   Returns the name of the browser.

This is false as `window.navigator.appName` in chrome returns `"NetScape"`

The `Navigator object is very poorly implemented in browsers

**Do not browser detect**

Comment: That doesn't provide "only the name" as the question specifies.

Comment: it isn't pedantry, extracting the browser name from the user agent isn't a trivial task (at least not for someone at the level where they are asking this kind of question).

Comment: @Quentin your correct. But since I dislike userAgent sniffing I'm not going to show him a regular expression to do it :)

Comment: Browser detection is a little over-rated.  It's good for what it does, but a lot of features are simply broken in IE.  There's no reliable way to test for the broken-ness, you just have to "Oh, this is IE, CORS doesn't work right" or "Oh, this is IE, caching doesn't work right" or "Oh, this is IE, box model doesn't work right or "Oh, this is IE, *garbage collection* doesn't work right"